# Auto select null option if the ngModel value is null

Tags: html, angular

I'm working on an Angular project, so I have a simple html `select` as:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="personalSettings.selectedTimeZone" class="form-control">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected value>Select your time zone</option>
    <option *ngFor="let timeZone of personalSettings.timeZoneList" [ngValue]="timeZone.id">
      {{ timeZone.description }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

As you can see I auto-select the value of select depending on `[(ngModel)]="personalSettings.selectedTimeZone"` incoming value from API, but I added a default option as:

```
 <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected value>Select your time zone</option>
```

What I want to achieve with this is to auto-select that null option if `personalSettings.selectedTimeZone` come null, but this is not selecting anything, just display a blank value, how can I achieve this?

Comment: are you sure that selectedTimeZone is null? It can be valorized as undefined instead?

Comment: Ohh, I check that, and it is an empty Guid 
"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" @Gone

Answer (score 0):

This is not displaying the default(null) value because it was receiving an empty guid from the API as default for `selectedTimeZone`, to solve this, I just changed the backend logic and returned a null value if it is an empty guid.